# TASM problems with output

Tags: tasm

So, I am a complete newcomer to TASM, so I'm probably making loads and loads of mistakes. This is one problem, however, I wish for some help with.

I need to assemble a program that takes the input from the user and replaces all gaps with the character before it (So, if the input is a b c, it should print aabbc). The problem I have is that I am getting garbage data printed out instead of what I need. I honestly don't know what the problem is, so I am requesting help with this.

Oh, and just in advance, I'm using DosBox on Windows 8.

Here is the code:

```
.MODEL SMALL ;defines memory model
.STACK 100H ;reserves memory space
.DATA
insert equ 0ah
outsert equ 9h
ENDL equ '$'
GAP equ ' '
;db 120h dup (?) ;reserve 120h bytes of space
Buff db 250
clen db ?
_chr db 250 dup (?) ;reserve 250 bytes of space for line
.CODE
START:
; initialization
push ds ; iveda Word/Doubleword i steka
sub cx, cx ; subtract
push cx
mov cx, ds ;ds = cx specifically moves the data segment
mov ds, cx ;cx = ds same as above

;user input
lea ax, Buff ;load address
mov ah, insert ;insert into ah
int 21h ;close

; putting length into cx
xor cx, cx
mov cl, clen
mov si, offset clen ;loads offset part

;if line is empty, end
cmp cx, 0 ;compare
;testing if end of the line
je FINISH

;string testing
CHECK:
dec cx ;decrement starting pointer by 1
inc si ;raise starting pointer by 1
cmp cx, 0 ;comparing if empty
je CONT ;jei paskutinis, tai baigiamas ciklas
cmp byte ptr [si], GAP ;2 operands compare
je CHANGE ;if gap found, then off to this cycle to change symbol
jmp CHECK
CHANGE:
mov bl, byte ptr [si+1]
mov [si], bl
jmp CHECK ;returning to cycle
CONT:
; '$' at end of buffer
; vi points at last symbol
inc si
mov bl, ENDL
mov [si], bl

;output onto screen
lea ax, Buff
add ax, 2 ;from the 3'rd byte
mov ah, outsert
int 21h; ;finsihing up, closing

;returning to DOS
FINISH:
mov cx, 4c00h ;exit
int 21h
END START
```

I apologize in advance if a similar question might have been answered already (I couldn't find anything from searching, though) and I thank you for answers.

Comment: You're reading from `clen` in a few places in your code, even though you haven't initialized it anywhere. The number of bytes read after `int 21h / ah=0ah` will be at `[Buff+1]`, and the actual character data will be at `[Buff+2]..[Buff+2+length-1]`

Comment: `lea ax, Buff` must be changed to `lea dx, Buff`

Comment: I think that clen does get initialized at `clen db ?`. Or does that not count?

Comment: I presume I need to change both instances of `lea ax, Buff`. I did so and it doesn't seem to spew loads of garbage data anymore, but it still doesn't seem to work perfectly. It seems to now do the opposite of what I need it to do: if I input a b c, it prints out abbcc when it should print aabbc.

Comment: @Anstane: `clen db ?` _declares_ a byte value named `clen` that can be accessed from the code, but its initial value is still undefined.